# Add btn after clone table tr

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to clone table tr and add new `btn` into `td` with class "rooms_btns".

How can I do that?

```js
$(".add_room_btn").on('click', function() {
  new_row_content = $("#clone_row").clone();
  new_row_content.removeAttr('id');
  new_row_content.append().append("<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x text-danger'></i></a>").insertAfter("#clone_row");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<table>
  <tr id="clone_row">
    <td>
      <select name="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">STANDART</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="rooms_btns">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x text-success add_room_btn"></i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code appears to already be doing what you describe...?

Comment: no, it's not adding the new html at the end of the td: `<td class="rooms_btns">`  @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append to the `.rooms_btns` cell within the cloned row you need to first select it before calling `append()`. To do this you can use `find()`:

```js
$(".add_room_btn").on('click', function() {
  var $new_row_content = $("#clone_row").clone();
  $new_row_content.removeAttr('id');
  $new_row_content.find('td.rooms_btns').append("<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x text-danger'></i></a>");
  $new_row_content.insertAfter("#clone_row");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<table>
  <tr id="clone_row">
    <td>
      <select name="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">STANDART</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="rooms_btns">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x text-success add_room_btn"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change jquery to this.

```
$(".add_room_btn").on('click', function() {
  new_row_content = $("#clone_row").clone();
  new_row_content.removeAttr('id');
  new_row_content.find('.rooms_btns').append("<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x text-danger'></i></a>");
  new_row_content.insertAfter("#clone_row");
});
```

you could then change your click handler to this
`$(document).on('click', ".add_room_btn", function() {`
so that all the dynamically added + buttons will work.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/L5yz1kwx/)**.

You need to append the cloned tr to the table :

```
$('table').append(new_row_content);
```

**NOTE:**

Remove the extra append in :

```
new_row_content.append().append("<a href='#' class='remove_room_btn'><i class='fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x text-danger'></i></a>").insertAfter("#clone_row");
_______________^^^^^^^^^
```

Should be :

```
new_row_content.append("<a href='#' class='remove_room_btn'><i class='fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x text-danger'></i></a>").insertAfter("#clone_row");
```